# when i start camera then its surface comes in just opposite 

Tags: android

my code for surface creation is:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if (camera == null) {
            try {
                Log.e("camera starting","camera starting");
                camera = android.hardware.Camera.open();
                Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                //final List<String> coloreffects = camera.getParameters().getSupportedColorEffects();
                mParameters.set("rotation","ANTIBANDING_60HZ");
                parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_SEPIA);
                parameters.getFocusMode();

                mParameters.set("rotation",90);
                parameters.setFocusMode("android.intent.extra.focus");
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.extra.focus");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

                camera.setParameters(parameters);
                Log.e("camera running","camera runnng");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this code. And change avd version 2.2

```
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
         camera = Camera.open();

         try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                parameters.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
                parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
                camera.setDisplayOrientation(90); 
                parameters.setRotation(90);
                camera.setParameters(parameters);
            }
            catch (IOException exception) {
                camera.release();
            }
        }
```

Comment: lovely answer, saved the day

Answer (score 0):

The reason this rotation is happening is that the Camera assumes the orientation to be
horizontal or landscape. The easiest way to correct the rotation is to make our activity
appear in landscape mode.

Add `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`  to your Activity in Manifest

or add this to your onCreate()

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: <activity android:name=".YourActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">

Comment: You need to add the last line to android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">